# Javascript in assets not loading in Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have added test.js to /assets/javascripts/

test.js only contains two lines

```
window.alert(5 + 6);
document.write(5 + 6);
```

application.js includes the following

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree 
//= require test
```

Inside of my view I have the following

```
<%= javascript_include_tag ("test") %>
```

But when I load the view there is no window alert or other output

I have tried adding to my initializers/assets and restarting the server but no change

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( test.js )
```

Any help would be wonderful, I'm surely missing something quite obvious..

Comment: Are there more files on your `assets/javascripts/` folder? or just the `application.js` and `test.js`? Your code should work, but if there are some other `.js` file being loaded by the `require_tree`, that other js file probably have some error... just guessing. Check the console on your browser

Comment: Yes there are no other JS files in there. 
When I view the page source it shows:
    <body>
    <script src="/assets/test.self-     d59630211a0503ec6c053d84ba2e4f01f5b3e15433fbad7d24f452e1221204    cb.js?body=1"></script>
    </body>

Comment: It's now working, I had another piece of javascript left in test.js. I removed it now working, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - the test.js had another line of javascript code which was interrupting the execution